# open form in new popup window of small size

Tags: html

I want to open new url as a popup window on form submission. Can you please help me .

Comment: I tried using onsubmit and added script tag in mason inside <%perl> tag. But it is not recognizing the script tag . Is teher any other way to include script tag inside mason.

Comment: Also, should i be using target tag along with onsubmit ?

Comment: Also, what happens if action and onsubmit attributes exists together on form element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FORM tag allows an onSubmit event handler which you can process JavaScript in.

You could do something like

```
<form ... onsubmit="return submitWindow">
</form>
```

And the JavaScript for opening the window

```
<script>
    function submitWindow() {
        ..
        // URL, name and attributes
        window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','windowNew','width=300, height=300');
        return true;
    }
```

Have a look at for more information on onSubmit:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

You could also add the window.open on your submit button using the onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

[source](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/learning_javascript_functions.php3)

```
function open_win(url_add)
   {
   window.open(url_add,'welcome',
   'width=300,height=200,menubar=yes,status=yes,
   location=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes');
   }
<form onsubmit="open_win('http://url')" ...>
```

If you want to submit the form depending popup open, then you must return true/false from the respective function(here open_win(url_add)).
And you have to use the return keyword on submit attr like - onsubmit="return open_win('url')

Answer (score 0):

use target attribute for form

```
<form ... onsubmit="return submitWindow" target="_new">



</form>
```